# Не все браузеры видят картинку

Tags: html, изображения, css

http://snegyrki.ru/

Под меню где идёт надпись - костюм деда мороза существует банер, но проблема в том, что ровно половина браузеров его видят, а половина нет- в чём причина?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего, причина в этом:

```
#baner {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 354px;
    background: url('images/baner.jpg') top no-repeat;
    font-family: MyCustomFont, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Что подтверждается показом картинки при отключённом адблоке и пропадании при включённом.

Answer (score 0):

в google chrome:

Ctrl+Shift+J -> читаем что красным пишет!